# Formula to Round Down Number in cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to round down the highlighted numbers in Column Q of the attached screenshot. I currently have formula of P/F starting on Cell Q5 through Q46. I am diving the quantity on hand for each part number by the Qty Used per build. Is there a round down formula I can use to incorporate the P/F formula so it can round down the number in each cell automatically?

Thank you in advance,
[image]
Juan

Comment: wrap your formula in the [`ROUNDDOWN()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rounddown-function-2ec94c73-241f-4b01-8c6f-17e6d7968f53#:~:text=ROUNDDOWN%20behaves%20like%20ROUND%2C%20except,down%20to%20the%20nearest%20integer.) formula?

Comment: Hi Scott, I have tried this already but I get a message saying "You've entered too few arguments for this function". Here is the formula I used ---- =ROUNDDOWN(P5/F5)

Comment: did you read the link? it showed you how to use the formula and would explain why you are getting that error. `=ROUNDDOWN(P5/F5,0)`